# Как взять только первую картинку из данного кода на патйон?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Как мне сохранить только первую картинку а не все?

Когда идёт цикл на 13-ой строке он извлекает картинки из id и сохраняет их.

Внизу пример кода.

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from link import bot, dp

async def userinfo(message: types message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    result = await bot.get_user_profile_photos(user_id)
    photos = result["photos"]

    if not photos:
        await message.answer("Нет фото!")
        return

    for photo sizes in photos:
        photo = max(photo_sizes, key=Lambda x: x["width"])
        file_id = photo["file id"]
        file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
        await bot.download_file(file.file_path, f"bot_cards/user_img-jpg")
def handler_message_userinfo(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(userinfo, commands=["userinfo"], commands_prefix="/!")
```

Comment: Ну убери цикл и сохраняй только первую в списке

Comment: Как это сделать подробнее ?

Comment: Что сделать подробнее? Ты написал такой код, но не знаешь как взять в списке первый элемент?

Comment: либо убери цикл, либо в конце цикла brake поставь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, замените вашу строку `for photo sizes in photos:` на `photo = photos[0]`. Это присвоит переменной `photo` только первый элемент списка `photos`, который содержит информацию о первой картинке пользователя:

```
async def userinfo(message: types message):
user_id = message.from_user.id
result = await bot.get_user_profile_photos(user_id)
photos = result["photos"]

if not photos:
    await message.answer("Нет фото!")
    return

photo = photos[0]
sizes = photo[-1]
file_id = sizes["file_id"]
file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
await bot.download_file(file.file_path, f"bot_cards/user_img-jpg")
```